# What does this R expression do?

Tags: r

`sp_full_in` is matrix:

```
   1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21
1  0 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 1  1  1  1  1  2  1  1  1  1  1  1  2
2  1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  1  1  2  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
3  2 2 0 2 2 2 2 2 2  1  1  2  2  2  1  2  1  1  1  2  1
4  1 2 1 0 2 2 2 1 2  1  1  1  2  2  1  2  1  1  2  2  1
5  2 2 2 2 0 2 2 2 2  1  1  2  1  2  1  2  1  1  1  2  2
6  2 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1  2  2  2  2  2  1  2  1  2  2  1  1
7  2 1 1 2 1 1 0 1 1  2  1  1  2  1  1  2  1  1  1  2  1
8  1 2 1 1 1 2 2 0 1  1  1  2  2  2  1  2  1  1  2  1  1
9  2 2 1 2 1 1 2 2 0  1  1  2  1  2  1  2  1  1  2  2  2
10 2 2 1 1 1 2 2 1 1  0  2  2  2  2  1  1  1  1  1  2  2
11 2 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 1  1  0  2  1  2  1  2  1  1  1  1  2
12 1 2 1 1 2 1 1 2 1  1  1  0  2  2  1  2  1  2  1  1  1
13 2 2 2 2 1 3 2 2 2  1  1  3  0  2  1  2  2  1  2  2  2
14 2 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1  2  2  2  1  0  1  2  1  1  1  1  1
15 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2  1  1  2  2  1  0  2  1  1  1  1  2
16 1 2 2 1 1 2 2 2 1  1  2  2  2  2  1  0  1  1  2  1  2
17 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 2 1  1  1  1  2  2  1  2  0  2  2  1  1
18 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1  1  1  2  1  1  1  1  2  0  1  1  1
19 2 2 1 2 1 2 2 2 2  1  1  2  2  2  1  2  1  1  0  2  2
20 2 2 1 1 1 2 2 2 2  1  2  2  2  2  1  2  1  1  1  0  1
21 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1  2  2  1  2  1  1  2  1  1  2  1  0

mean(sp_full_in[which(sp_full_in != Inf)])
```

produces the result `[1] 1.38322`

I'm not quite sure I understand what this does, but the way I read it is: for every cell in sp_full_in, check if it is *not* infinite, if so, return the output 1, then average all the outputs. Is that correct? If not, how should it be ready?

Comment: It calculates the mean of all the values that are not Inf. In other words, it finds all the values that are not Inf and calculates the mean of that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`which(sp_full_in != Inf)` returns a vector of integers (and only one of them is 1). That vector of integers is then handed to "[" as indices into `sp_full_in` and  returns all the values of `sp_full_in` as a vector passed to the `mean` function.

It is a good idea to learn to read R expressions from the "inside out". Find the innermost function call and mentally evaluate it, in this case `sp_full_in != Inf`,. That returns a logical matrix of all TRUE's that gets passed to `which()`, and since there is no 'arr.ind' argument, it returns an atomic vector of indices.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are good at explaining why you get the mean of all the finite entries in the matrix, but it's worth noting that in this case the `which` **does nothing**. I used to have the bad habit of over-using `which` as well.

```
> a <- matrix(rnorm(4), nrow = 2)
> a
           [,1]       [,2]
[1,]  0.5049551 -0.7844590
[2,] -1.7170087 -0.8509076
> a[which(a != Inf)]
[1]  0.5049551 -1.7170087 -0.7844590 -0.8509076
> a[a != Inf]
[1]  0.5049551 -1.7170087 -0.7844590 -0.8509076
> a[1] <- Inf
> a
          [,1]       [,2]
[1,]       Inf -0.7844590
[2,] -1.717009 -0.8509076
> a[which(a != Inf)]
[1] -1.7170087 -0.7844590 -0.8509076
## Similarly if there was an Infinite value
> a[a != Inf]
[1] -1.7170087 -0.7844590 -0.8509076
```

And, while we're at it, we should also mention the function `is.finite` which is often preferable to `!= Inf`. `is.finite` will return `FALSE` on `Inf`, `-Inf`, `NA` and `NaN`.

Answer (score 0):

No, but you are close, when *which* is applied to a matrix, it checks every cell of the matrix against the condition,here it is Not Inf. Return the indices of all cells satisfying the conditions,then, according to your code, output the value of the cell according to the returned indices and finally calculate mean of those.

Comment: Who does "No, but you are close" refer to? It's an ambiguous way of communicating in a thread that reconfigures itself based on votes.

Comment: ok,"which" will give you indices. According to the indices,you can retrieve values and get their average.